# Close all modals and then open the clicked one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with multiple modals. Half of the website (left side) has a table, and the the other half (right side) has the space for the modals to be displayed.

When you click on any of the row in the table, a corresponding modal appears in the right space. So if the table has 5 rows it has 5 corresponding modals that should appear depending on which row you've clicked.

What I want is that when you click on a row, the corresponding modal appears. I've already done this. However, what I want further to do is that when you click on another row, the corresponding modal appears. **However**, this new modal may overlaps the previously open modal, or it may appear behind (either of these two options).

This is the problem. If you've already clicked on a row and it has opened 
its corresponding modal, and then you click on another row, first the modal must be closed, and then this row's corresponding modal should appear.
No Bootstrap allowed.

I have the following code, but I still need to close it somehow, plus creating the code for all 5 rows.

```
    <!-- Modals --> <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('B1000C42LMG2-12_details');
    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("B1000C42LMG2-12");
    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {modal.style.display = "block";}
</script>
```

*I'd like to clarify that I don't actually have 5 rows, it's just to make it easier for you. **There about 69 rows in reality***.

Any question/doubts please comment.

Comment: You can assign a class to all modals and on clicking any row close all modals with the help of that class before displaying respective modal.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark all of your modal by same className
For example: class="my-modal-to-close"
Then, make use of document.getElementsByClassName("my-modal-to-close") 
It will return an array of element, which are all of your modal box
Then, try to close as this bellow code

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("my-modal-to-close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display= "none";
}
```

Then, open the clicked one,

```
btn.onclick = function() {
modal_to_display.style.display = "block";
}
```

and all in

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("my-modal-to-close");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display= "none";
    }
    modal_to_display.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: `this` will refer to the `btn` in the `onclick` function

Answer (score 1):

Register your "opened" modal in a variable.
Once you click to open a new modal, you check your variable if another modal is already open. If yes close it. Then open the new modal.

```
<!-- Modals -->
<script>
var openedModal;
// Get the modal
function closeModalIfOpen() {
    if (typeof(openedModal) == 'undefined') {
        return;
    }
    openedModal.style.display = "none";
}
var modal = document.getElementById('B1000C42LMG2-12_details');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("B1000C42LMG2-12");
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    closeModalIfOpen();
    modal.style.display = "block";
    openedModal = modal;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Will store the currently opened modal element.
var currentModal;

// Get all the buttons (use the appropriate selector).
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

// Iterate through all buttons.
buttons.forEach(function(button){
    // Get the modal that corresponds to this button.
    var modal = document.getElementById(button.id + '_details');

    // When this button is clicked...
    button.onclick = function(){
        // Close the currently open modal if there is one.
        if(currentModal){
            currentModal.style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Open the modal for this button and set it as the current modal.
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        currentModal = modal;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all modals a class (in this example `modal`)   and use the following function before showing your desired modal

```
function closeAllModals() {
    var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
    for(var i=0; i<modals.length; i++) {
        modals[i].style.display = 'none' ; 
    }
}
```